# Error: "Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:

Tags: web3js, ether, ethereumjs, web3js-v1.x, meta-transactions

I'm facing a little issue here, that's the mintTo function from contract for NFT. Which I require the sender to send a value with **>=** **0.1 Ether**:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


import "./TradeableERC721Token.sol";
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol";

/**
 * @title Creature
 * Creature - a contract for my non-fungible creatures.
 */
contract Creatures is TradeableERC721Token {
  constructor(address _proxyRegistryAddress) TradeableERC721Token("Creatures", "CRE", _proxyRegistryAddress) public {  }


  function baseTokenURI() public view returns (string memory) {
    return "https://metadata-link.com/api/tokens/";
  }
}


pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol';
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';
import './Strings.sol';

 contract TradeableERC721Token is ERC721Full, Ownable {
  using Strings for string;

  address proxyRegistryAddress;
  uint256 private _currentTokenId = 0;

  constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, address _proxyRegistryAddress) ERC721Full(_name, _symbol) public {
    proxyRegistryAddress = _proxyRegistryAddress;
  }


  /**
      * @dev Mints a token to an address with a tokenURI.
      * @param _to address of the future owner of the token
      */
  function mintTo(address _to) public payable {
    require(msg.value >= 0.1 ether);
    address contractOwner = owner();
    address(uint160(contractOwner)).transfer(msg.value);
    uint256 newTokenId = _getNextTokenId();
    _mint(_to, newTokenId);
    _incrementTokenId();
  }

  /**
    * @dev calculates the next token ID based on value of _currentTokenId 
    * @return uint256 for the next token ID
    */
  function _getNextTokenId() private view returns (uint256) {
    return _currentTokenId.add(1);
  }

  /**
    * @dev increments the value of _currentTokenId 
    */
  function _incrementTokenId() private  {
    _currentTokenId++;
  }

  function baseTokenURI() public view returns (string memory) {
    return "";
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (string memory) {
    return Strings.strConcat(
        baseTokenURI(),
        Strings.uint2str(_tokenId)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Override isApprovedForAll to whitelist user's OpenSea proxy accounts to enable gas-less listings.
   */
  function isApprovedForAll(
    address owner,
    address operator
  )
    public
    view
    returns (bool)
  {
    // Whitelist OpenSea proxy contract for easy trading.
    ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
    if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.isApprovedForAll(owner, operator);
  }
}
```

And Then from the client I use **web3@1.0.0-beta.34** to call **mintTo** function:

```js
    const web3 = window.web3;

    const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(NFT_ABI, NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, { gasLimit: "1000000" });

    const minterAccount = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const minter = minterAccount[0];
    const result = await nftContract.methods.mintTo(minter).send({
      from: minter,
      value: web3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether"),
      gas: "25000",
    })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
```

Then, I get this error:

```js
Error: "Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:
{
  "blockHash": "0x9b477437e6fef51a85f0700099d4b765b199bc412dcbd912daacdfc3b1337140",
  "blockNumber": 6207136,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 139877,
  "from": "0x34b8d058df685de17c64b46248d4794ff87bb458",
  "gasUsed": 21678,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x5b40cde4bde153fef88ba435cf18d7433b4113f8",
  "transactionHash": "0xe9af511d933eca45d633799eada763950fee7d622c7f5b49601058fc96ed8ca8",
  "transactionIndex": 4,
  "events": {}
}"
```

I've changed send options to:

```js
    const result = await nftContract.methods.mintTo(minter).send({
      from: minter,
      value: web3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether"),
      gasLimit: "25000",
    })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });

// And

   const result = await nftContract.methods.mintTo(minter).send({
      from: minter,
      value: web3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether"),
      gas: 25000,
    })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
```

Also got the same error, I did my search but didn't figured out where is the issue from. 
Thanks for Help.

Comment: You obviously need to provide more than 25000 gas for executing this function.

Comment: And BTW, what's the point in `address(uint160(contractOwner))` when `contractOwner` is already an address type???

Comment: I've tried to change the gas many times to more higher than 25000 but get the same error also!!

Comment: I've added `address(uint160())` to be able to change it to payable account and then can receive the value

Comment: Post the entire contract, so we can give it a try.

Comment: Please don't expect anyone here to download a file. Post it here in plain text.

Comment: All right, I've updated the post with the contract, and thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `contractOwner` happen to be the address of some other contract (i.e., not just an externally-owned account)?

Comment: I've updated the post, contractOwner is the owner address of Creatures NFT contract, which it inherits from TradeableERC721Token. And I required 0.1 ether from the minter to mint and then send this value to the owner. I've tested the scenario in remix and it works fine btw.

Comment: So here is a simple debug method for you: 1. Mask out (comment) all lines in the function, and then make sure that the transaction completes successfully. 2. Start adding those lines one by one, and each time execute the transaction until it fails. 3. Investigate the line which causes the failure, or publish your findings here so that others can advise on them.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for help and advice.

Comment: No problem. Have you managed to resolve the problem or find the source of it?

Answer (score 0):

`Error: "Transaction ran out of gas. Please provide more gas:`

This happens when you want to execute a transaction that requires **X** amount of gas for successful execution but you send gas **less than X**.

Solution:

- On Ganache: the default gasLimit is **6721975** you can pass that value as the gasLimit for the execution of your transaction.
- On other networks say Ropsten, Rinkeby, Kovan, Goerli etc you can use web3's estimateGas function to get a rough idea about how much gas will your transaction take for its successful execution

```
Example: 
    const Web3 = require('web3');
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://SERVER_IP:PORT"));

    web3.eth.estimateGas(callObject [, callback])

    web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe",
    data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
    })
    .then(console.log);
    > "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015"
```

In order to be on the safer side pass a value which is greater than the output of **estimateGas**

[Web3 estimateGas API](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#estimategas)

Comment: 6721975 is most likely already many times more than he needs for this function to execute (unless there is a lot that we don't know about the call-tree inside it). In addition to that, he already write in a comment that he's tried to change the gas many times to more higher than 25000 but still getting the same error.

Comment: I've tried `nftContract.methods.mintTo.estimateGas()` and it outputs '21678', then I changed `gas: 21678` and changed it many times with higher than that but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

All type of Ethereum transaction requires gas.
When we make the transaction, we can set the gas limit so that the transaction use the gas to the limit. If the transaction requires more gas than gas limit, then the EVM revert the transaction. This helps users not to use too much transaction fee for the transaction.

Anyway, the reason why you faced the error is because you set low gas fee for the transaction.

Normal ether send transaction require 21000 gas and normal mint requires about 43000(or may require much more).
So for the perfect transaction, I would like you to set the gas limit as 1000000.
And also, seems like you did not set the transaction type and priority fees.

So the send code must be like this.

```
const result = await nftContract.methods.mintTo(minter).send({
  from: minter,
  value: web3.utils.toWei("0.1", "ether"),
  gasLimit: "1000000",
  type: 2,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toWei("1", "gwei"),
  maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toWei("50", "gwei"),
})
  .on('error', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
```